# Is there a quick (command line) way to find out which style file needs to be used for a command (without using an Internet connection)?

Tags: documentation

So far, whenever I needed to know where exactly a command (or my fuzzy concept about some specific task) has been defined, I have used a search engine to find it out.

But if I know about the particular (specific) package, we can use `texdoc`.
For example, if we need to read more about the `graphicx` package, we use,

```
texdoc graphicx
```

and that particular documentation pops up.

Now, let us say that I know about the command `\AtBeginEnvironment`, but not sure which style file to be used for this. Is there any other  way than using a web search engine to find out that indeed `etoolbox` needs to be used?

If I use,

```
texdoc AtBeginEnvironment
```

I get,

```
Sorry, no documentation found for AtBeginEnvironment.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.
```

Taking this one step further, let us say that I have a fuzzy concept of things to be done (put some command at environment start e.g.), but do not exactly know how to achieve this, is there a way to point me to the correct packages? Again, not using search engine?

I understand that we all have got used to having Internet at hand take and it for granted. But things get a little difficult when Internet access 
is limited or completely unavailable.

Comment: You mean besides `grep`?

Comment: Google with `<query> site:tex.stackexchange.com` is pretty quick.

Comment: @erik You missed the basic requirement, *without using a search engine*.

Comment: While my comment wasn't entirely serious, I admit I didn't read the post carefully enough to see that search engines are excluded. If that is indeed basic requirement, perhaps it should be stated in the title.

Comment: I think, really, you mean "without an internet connection"? It is, after all, possible to open the CTAN page and search without an 'Internet search engine' in the usual sense. The point, surely, is that you want an ***offline*** option.

Comment: Remember that macro definitions are sometimes embedded in other definitions or in constructs beginning with `\csname`, so a complete search would essentially need to parse TeX. But if your hopes are more modest, check out [tlwhich](https://github.com/akerbos/scripts/blob/master/tlwhich). However, it's capabilities could be expanded fairly easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tlmgr` to search for information about installed packages using filename, long and short description, for example. This is not a search for *commands*. It is more like CTAN's search but less powerful. You can use regular expressions etc.

You will not always get a complete set of results. For example, searching for `patch` does not return `etoolbox`:

```
$ tlmgr search patch
HA-prosper - Patches and improvements for prosper.
issuulinks - Produce external links instead of internal ones.
jknapltx - Miscellaneous packages by Joerg Knappen.
ltabptch - Bug fix for longtable.
lualatex-math - Fixes for mathematics-related LuaLaTeX issues
marginfix - Patch \marginpar to avoid overfull margins.
memoir - Typeset fiction, non-fiction and mathematical books.
oberdiek - A bundle of packages submitted by Heiko Oberdiek.
ogham - Fonts for typesetting Ogham script.
patch - Patch loaded packages, etc..
patchcmd - Change the definition of an existing command.
pittetd - Electronic Theses and Dissertations at Pitt.
realscripts - Access OpenType subscript and superscript glyphs.
regexpatch - High level patching of commands.
shapepar - A macro to typeset paragraphs in specific shapes.
sphack - Patch LaTeX kernel spacing macros.
tamefloats - Experimentally use \holdinginserts with LaTeX floats.
xltxtra - "Extras" for LaTeX users of XeTeX.
xpatch - Extending etoolbox patching commands.
```

Although the final result does at least mention `etoolbox`.

Similarly, you can use `texdoc` to search for a word, but only in the path names of files. So this option is more limited than the search provided by `tlmgr` which also searches the package descriptions.

```
$ texdoc -l patch
 1 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/patchcmd/patchcmd.pdf
   = Package documentation
 2 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/regexpatch/regexpatch.pdf
   = Package documentation
 3 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/xpatch/xpatch.pdf
   = Package documentation
 4 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/regexpatch/README
   = Readme
 5 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/xpatch/README
   = Readme
 6 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/oberdiek/hopatch.pdf
 7 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/patches.txt
 8 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/flabels/makedoc-patched
Please enter the number of the file to view, anything else to skip:
```

If you are really desperate, you can search for all package files, say, and then search those files for a pattern. On a Unix-ish system, for example, `find $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN)/tex/latex -path '*.sty'` and then run something like `grep '\\AtBeginEnvironment'` on the results. But you would need to be reasonably desperate (but not in a hurry!) to do this. On the other hand, if you have an idea of the package it might be in, just grepping half a dozen package files is extremely fast.

Comment: ok, deleting my comment. good answer by the way, nice to see `tlmgr search` mentioned as it got an enhancement and searches in more places with TL2015.

Comment: ah sorry, actually I meant `tlmgr info` which since `TL2015` provides more extant results. Which however is less appropriate in this context than `tlmgr search` (`tlmgr info patch` finds the package with that name and nothing else). I will end up deleting this and the previous comment too... (after a while)

Comment: Thanks. I think `tlmgr` is under-appreciated.

Comment: on `Mac OS X`, `TLU` provides a very nice graphical interface; for some years I used only that. But a few months back I needed to install TeXLive on a Linux box all by myself, and at last started using `tlmgr` during the pretest period of `TL2015`,  also on my Mac. Since, I returned to `TLU` for `99%` of the time on the Mac, but being now familiar with `tlmgr` from Linux side, I have grown to appreciate its possibilities. (of which I use only a tiny fraction)

Comment: I've never used (or even seen) the/a GUI version, though obviously I know they exist.

Comment: I tried (once) the how was it called `Tk` or something interface on my earlier Mac laptop, which worked under `X11`. The TeX Live Utility appeared on the Mac, and it provided all I needed in a native Mac interface. It is so good it delayed by a number of years my becoming familiar with the command line `tlmgr`.